# Как поменять кодировку в php коде?

Tags: php

Есть файл с кодом который вызывает rss для показа на сайте. Но кодировка rss.xml  encoding="windows-1251" и когда выводится лента на страницу то показываются крякозябры. Весь сайт на utf 8 кодировки, пробовал менять на самой странице в head нечего не выходит ?

```
    <?php

function print_rss($url_rss,$file_rss,$hclock,$kol_print_news)
  {



    if (!file_exists($file_rss))
      {
       if (@!copy ($url_rss,$file_rss))
         return (false);
      }
     else
       {

        if (filemtime($file_rss) + $hclock*60*60 < time())
          {
           if (@!copy ($url_rss,$file_rss))
             return (false);
          }
       }


    $text_rss=file($file_rss);
    $text_rss=implode("",$text_rss);

    $mas_item=array();
    preg_match_all("#<item>.*?</item>#is",$text_rss,$mas_item);

    $t="";
    $kol=0;
    if (sizeof($mas_item)>0)
      {

       foreach ($mas_item[0] as $one_item)
         {
          $kol++;
          $t_is=preg_match("#<title>(.*?)</title>#is",$one_item,$title);
          $l_is=preg_match("#<link>(.*?)</link>#is",$one_item,$link);
          $d_is=preg_match("#<description>(.*?)</description>#is",$one_item,$description);
          if ($t_is and $l_is)
            {
             $title[1]=preg_replace("#<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>#eis","'\\1'",$title[1]);
             $link[1]=preg_replace("#<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>#eis","'\\1'",$link[1]);
             $description[1]=preg_replace("#<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>#eis","'\\1'",$description[1]);
             $t.="<div><a href='".$link[1]."' target='_blank'>".$title[1]."</a> <br>".$description[1]."</div>";
            }
          if ($kol >= $kol_print_news) break;
         }
      }

    echo ($t);


    return (true);
  }
```

Comment: `Но кодировка rss.xml encoding="windows-1251"`, а в чем проблема написать `utf-8` или доступа к `rss` нет? Если нет, пробовать конвертировать через `iconv` прилетающий текст с `rss`. И вобоще, зачем тулите `@` - плохая практика, да и `echo ()` зачем скобки? И `return (true)` что вы пытаетесь сделать скобками?

Comment: Пробовал В место русских и латинских символов квадратики. Если написано слово на английском то отображается. Повторю: Если слово на латинице используя латинские буквы написанные по русски не отображается. Если просто русскими то тоже нет. Только слова написанные по английски отображаются к примеру Opel или Bmw будут отображаться. А к примеру Maha уже не будет отображаться а Masha будет !

Comment: https://helpsetup.ru/rss/rss1.php сами посмотрите !

Comment: На ваш вопрос >> И вобоще, зачем тулите @ - плохая практика, да и echo () зачем скобки? И return (true) что вы пытаетесь сделать скобками? >> Это кэш используется

Comment: Это говорит о том, что вы не конвертнули правильно кодировку, покажите где находится `rss`, добавьте в свой вопрос, не нужно писать код в комментах, если хотите, чтобы быстрее помогли, отредактируйте вопрос максимально понятно, с минимальным рабочим примером и укажите на проблему. Кто вам такое сказал, что там какой-то кеш `echo ("")` или `return ("")` если писать скобки? Вы серьезно?

Comment: $t=iconv("Windows-1251","UTF-8",$t); Помогло но теперь он показывает только один пост из ленты в место 10 ???

Comment: Я выложил максимально рабочий ? Что еще надо я не понимаю ?

Comment: Потом не True как Вы написали а False )))

Comment: Не нужно у `echo` скобок - это не функция, а конструкция языка, так-же поддерживается перечисление переменных через запятую `echo 1, "string", (2+5)`, будет работать быстрее, чем использовать конкатенацию " `.` ". А `@` - это плохой тон, подавление ошибок таким образом,может привести потом к неразберихи, и отладка будет не удобна. Лучше пойти путем отслеживания ошибок и разобраться в чем именно произошла ошибка со всеми ее вытекающими.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем в код         `$t=iconv("Windows-1251","UTF-8",$t);`